# Calculating Run Totals for lengths of Pipe & Pile

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to calculate a run cost and I need help with a procedure to copy a columns row value to the next row when its value is 0. Here I would like to copy the 0.99 from row 2 to rows 3 & 4 where they're 0. After this I would like to move the 0.66 forward and then the 0.36. I hope this formats nicely this is my first post here. Thanks for any help.

```
lngPipeRunID    lngPipeGroupID  lngInOutID  RunLoadFootage  RunFootage  RunLoadCost RunCostFoot
1   1   1   4549.0000   4549.0000   4503.51     0.99
2   1   1   -1523.2200  3025.7800   -1507.99    0.99
3   1   2   -2491.7300  534.0500    0.00        0.00
4   1   2   -96.0000    438.0500    0.00        0.00
5   1   1   8471.6800   8909.7300   11930.92    1.4083
6   2   1   261.0000    261.0000    172.26      0.66
7   2   1   221.4200    482.4200    0.00        0.00
8   2   1   1191.5100   1673.9300   428.94      0.36
9   2   2   -1673.9300  0.0000      0.00        0.00
10  2   1   42.9800     42.9800     0.00        0.00
11  2   2   -42.9800    0.0000      0.00        0.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below query

```
   declare @tb table ( ln          int
,                   RunCostFoot money ) insert into @tb
values ( 1,  0.99   )
,      ( 2,  0.99   )
,      ( 3,  0.00   )
,      ( 4,  0.00   )
,      ( 5,  1.4083 )
,      ( 6,  0.66   )
,      ( 7,  0.00   )
,      ( 8,  0.36   )
,      ( 9,  0.00   )
,      ( 10, 0.00   )
,      ( 11, 0.00   )

;with cte ( rno
,           val )
as
(
    select ln as rno
    ,      RunCostFoot as val
    from @tb
    where ln=1
    union all
    select rno+1 as rno
    ,      case when RunCostFoot =0 then val
                                    else RunCostFoot end as val
    from @tb t
    join cte   on t.ln=cte.rno+1
)
select *
from cte
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want it to perform, with my limited knowledge I'm trying to implement this on a table called 'tbl_Pipe_Run' with no success. Not too sure what to do next so I'll post what I've created as an answer and see what that does, Thanks Dudi.

Comment: I see I have to figure out formatting, thanks for your response Nasser.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, is there a way to update RunCostFoot with val?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE spPipeRun_09_upd_RunCostFoot

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

DECLARE 

@ID INT = NULL,
@RCF MONEY = NULL

SELECT
    @ID = lngPipeRunID,
    @RCF = RunCostFoot
FROM
    tbl_Pipe_Run
WHERE
    lngPipeRunID = @ID;

WITH cte (RNO, VAL) AS
(
    SELECT lngPipeRunID AS RNO,
           RunCostFoot AS VAL
    FROM tbl_Pipe_Run
    WHERE lngPipeRunID=1
    UNION all
    SELECT RNO+1 as RNO
    ,      CASE WHEN RunCostFoot =0 then VAL
                                    else RunCostFoot end as VAL
    FROM tbl_Pipe_Run t
    join cte   ON t.lngPipeRunID=cte.RNO+1
)
SELECT *
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0)
END;
```